# CSS Style not applying to all pages

Tags: css

I've been trying to solve this problem for about 10 hours now and it's driving me nuts. I've googled and I've googled some more.

My problem is I'm trying to append a CSS doc and it works...but only for a couple pages. I did it the way I'm supposed to. I went to my master page section and added an alternate CSS URL. Then I go to my home page it looks fine but then as soon as I go to a page with a path like /my/name/ it stops appending my CSS doc to the head section.

All I'm trying to do is hide a couple links on the left navigation.

Here are some screen caps to show my prob.

[image: Working]

[image: Not working]

Comment: Are you sure the paths are in the same site? Did you try to use the checkbox to apply it to this site and all subsites?

Comment: Ya I checked the paths. And this is the main site with no subsites. Thanks though.

Comment: What strikes me about your screenshots is that in one of them you seem to have different permissions as you are missing the edit buttons on one. I would think your issue could be related to that. Also, are you sure this is not an issue in the CSS? Sometimes SP applies weird classes in certain states of pages that require specific CSS rules.

Comment: Ya the edit button is one the things I was hiding. So it worked on the one but not the other. I also just double checked the class names and they seem to be the same. li.static:nth-child(3) and etc. Thanks again though. This is just making me want to pull my hair out lol.

Comment: Also it appears you are on different site collections, the alternate CSS link does not break site collection boundaries. It has to be configured on each site.

Comment: Well Eric that appears to be it. I've never worked on Sharepoint before and I'm just helping my SharePoint team at work. I asked the main guy about site collections and he's like OH! that might be it....and I'm just like >_<....THANK YOU THOUGH!  And Thank you Jan for helping as well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you applied the css to the My Site Host. Your second screen shot is a Personal MySite, which is a different site collection. In fact, every user get their own personal my site (a site collection where they are site collection admin).

To apply consistent branding and stylesheet, you should look for branding my site host and personal my site. Since you're on on-prem this should be doable. Use feature stapling together with powershell to apply alternate css or custom master page. To better understand the difference, look up some architecture diagram.